# Iphone OpengGL ES: Camera view issue

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am making a kind of first person game but my view seems to be off.  It seems to rotate around a place a bit in front of me.  This causes issues on collision as when I hit a wall and rotate, I can rotate around in to (and behind) the wall.

Setup the view:

```
const GLfloat zNear = 0.1, zFar = 1000.0, fieldOfView = 120.0; 
GLfloat size = zNear * tanf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(fieldOfView) / 8.0);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

//Rotate the view
glRotatef(-90,0,0,1);

CGRect rect = self.view.bounds; 
glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height),
           size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height), zNear, zFar);

glViewport(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

The actual camera view

```
//view : prebaked in to OPenGL Template
gluLookAt(eye[0], eye[1], eye[2],center[0], center[1], center[2], 0.0, 1, 0.0);
```

I guessing I need to review the gluLookAt function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it was there glTranslatef(0, 0, -3);